# Is list a monad and comonad?

Tags: list, monads, comonad

The list monad is [given here](https://www.schoolofhaskell.com/school/starting-with-haskell/basics-of-haskell/13-the-list-monad).  Also see Spivak's [paper here](http://arxiv.org/abs/1209.1011).  So list is a monad.  Is it a comonad?  How would you prove that?

Comment: You can't define extract `[a] -> a` for finite lists.

Answer (score 1):

The list type constructor `a ↦ μ L. 1 + a * L` doesn't admit a comonad structure. Recall that if it were a comonad, we'd have (using the names from Haskell's `Functor` and `Comonad` typeclasses)

```
fmap :: ∀  a b. (a → b) → [a] → [b]
extract :: ∀  a. [a] → a
duplicate :: ∀  a. [a] → [[a]]
```

However, even without going into any required laws, `extract` cannot be implemented, since its input could be the empty list, giving no way to come up with an `a`.

The nonempty list type constructor `a ↦ μ NE. a + a * NE` does admit a comonad structure, with `extract` returning the first element, and `duplicate` mapping `[x, y, ..., z]` to `[[x], [x, y], ..., [x, y, ..., z]]` (note that each of them are non-empty by construction).

Comment: This `duplicate` does not obey almost any of the laws of comonads. A correct one (which is not unique) is something like `[x0..xn] -> [[x0..xn],[x1..xn,x0]..[xn,x0..xn-1]]`.